# Credible interval BCI in R

Tags: credible-interval

I used BCI to calculate the credible interval
I had 3 parameters alpha, gamma and delta and the result is

```
BCI(mc1)#default 95%
     0.025     0.975     post_mean
alpha 6.086810  9.458011  7.692283
gamma 6.381115 15.355804 10.334151
delta 6.524433 16.210562 10.786478
```

My question:

How can I read this matrix?

Is 6.086810 is the lower limit and 9.458011 is the upper limit for paramter alpha?

Answer (score 1):

Then answer is: Yes. The second column represents the 2.5% quantile and the third column represents the 97.5% quantile of the confidence interval. Then, the 95% BCI is $(6.086810,  9.458011)$.

Recall that there are several types of bootstrap intervals:

http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ss/1032280214

and that most of them are already implemented in the R package 'boot':

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/boot/boot.pdf

Comment: A confidence interval has two *endpoints,* not quantiles.